# Is it possible to get notifications when files/folders are accessed from my iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud, notifications

I think my housemate may be accessing my iCloud Drive from my MacBook when I'm not at home.

Is there any way to enable notifications on my phone when someone accesses a folder on my iCloud drive?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to change the password? If they need to use the Mac, set them up a standard account.

Comment: Harder way to go can be to disable and enable iCloud drive every time. And a password in system preferences would stop them from enabling it when you’re away.